# ANDROID-How is 16bit-PCM encoded audio sampling data(16bit) saved in buffer which is in units of byte(8bit)

Tags: pcm, android-audiorecord

`audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 8000,
                  AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                  bufferSizeInBytes); 
readsize = audioRecord.read(audiodata, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);`

So,

Q1. how is the 16bit PCM encoded sampling point is saved in the andiodata which is consist of bytes(8bit)? someone says every two bytes saves one sampling point while someone just ignores it.

Q2. if so which is the high 8bit? the audiodata[2*i] or audiodata[2*i+1]?

Q3. shall we consider the sign issue when we return to 16bit sampling point by two bytes?

Answer (score 0):

finally, i got the answer:instead of saving in byte (which seems to be a common misunderstanding and all programmer are doing like this), i save the sampling data in a short type buffer, this avoids the three problems mentioned above. i have approved the sampling effectiveness by signal with different frequency generated from matlab. the code is as follow:

```
       `short[] audiodata = new short[bufferSizeInBytes/2]; 
        readsize = audioRecord.read(audiodata, 0, bufferSizeInBytes/2); 
        `
```

this is the real sampling value for FFT and digital communication from earphone interface.